# Unable to open MONyogs

Tags: sqlite, monitoring

I was trying to run through the [docs for manually working](http://blog.webyog.com/2009/07/29/monyog-database-schema-explained/) with the MONyog internal sqlite dbs for purposes of configuration automation.

At the point trying to open the data file I get an error

```
$ sqlite ./connection.data 
Unable to open database "./connection.data": file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I've made sure the actual file is world readable (and writable even).  I've tried both the stock SQLite command line client as well as the Firefox plugin suggested in the doc mentioned about.

I'm pretty sure this file is a SQL lite database file

```
$ head -c 16 ./connection.data 
SQLite format 3
```

Any clues on how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you really starting a program named `sqlite`?

Comment: Yes. What's your real question or comment?

Comment: Not `sqlite3`? What version are you using?

Comment: 2.8.17.  Looks like that's what was packaged for my version of ubuntu.  I tried on a centos box that has sqlite3 (3.6.20).  It doesn't error right away but get the message after trying .databases in the shell

Comment: Both `sqlite3` on Ubuntu and SQLite Manager should have a recent enough version.